# Does the difficulty setting have any impact on the results of Interceptor dogfight?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

My question is pretty much asked within the title. Basically, I just want to know what, if anything, the Difficulty Setting affects in terms of Aerial Combat.

Will my Interceptors struggle more in Classic than in Normal?  Or will I begin to see bigger, stronger UFO's sooner in a higher difficulty game?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the UFO are not stronger, but rather your interceptor equipment is typically inferior at the same point in the game due to cash flow problems, which makes that aspect of the game more difficult anyway. That said, interceptors are not time critical and basic one will almost always defeat a scout, so you have a few months to prepare.

Comment: Cool, thank you.  I felt through Normal at least that upgrading my Interceptors seemed a bit superfluous.  The first gun upgrade carried me easily to the Plasma Cannon, which seemed good enough for pretty much everything the game threw at me.  Eventually got the Firestorm, but never felt like I needed it, other than perhaps to keep speed with the Overseer UFO.  Even Battleships were doable with the basic Raven+Plasma Cannon+Dodge/Aim.  Was hoping that Classic forced me to keep up with Aerial upgrades a bit more strongly.

Comment: Yeah I think some of the overhaul mods improve the UFO experience to make them tougher. might want to look into those

Comment: Aye, unfortunately I'm currently strictly an XBox user, though I'm working on getting a decent PC put together so that I can can make the switch back over the PC Gaming.  Thanks again man!